# Call function from another activity class in android studio

Tags: android

I have crated two activities. The first one has a timer I want to call a method from the first activity in the second one so I can stop the timer from clicking a button in second activity. The function that I want to call names as buClickpause in the code below
`    package com.example.user.timer;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnstart,btnpuse,btnstop;
TextView textTimer;
Handler customhandler=new Handler();
long startaatime=0L,timeInMilliseconds=0L,timeSwapBuff=0L,updateTime=0L;
Runnable updateTimerThred=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        timeInMilliseconds=SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-startaatime;
        updateTime=timeSwapBuff+timeInMilliseconds;
        int secs=(int)updateTime/1000;
        int mins=secs/60;
        secs%=60;
        int millisecomds=(int)(updateTime%1000);
        textTimer.setText(""+mins+":"+String.format("%02d",secs)
  +":"+String.format("%03d",millisecomds));
        customhandler.postDelayed(this,0);

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textTimer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

  }
  public void onClickstart(View view){
   startaatime= SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
   customhandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThred,0);

 }
  public void onClickpauase(View view){
    timeSwapBuff=timeInMilliseconds;
    customhandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThred);
 }
```

}`

Comment: post the second class

Comment: there is no code in the second class just a button when clicked it  call the onClickpuase function from the first class

Answer (score 0):

What would you achieve by calling a method in another Activity? If the calling activity is active, then the other activity isn't and a call to one of it's methods doesn't make sense.

So the answer to your question is "You can't".

I advise you to redesign your app, and put methods that need to be called from Activities in classes that aren't activities themselves. There are various methods to share methods and instances of classes, like static methods in utility classes, or dependency injection of Singleton classes.

Comment: The idea is that I want each user when start the app a timer will start counting in the first activity, and when he reach the last activity he must click a button that will stop the timer and the time will be in a database. Can you give me an idea to do it and thanks

Comment: Start the timer in onCreate or onStart, stop it in onPause and store it in a db (or file or preferences). Alternative is to store it in a separate class/instance that remains active independent of your activities. I usually use dependency injection (Toothpick, Dagger), so you'd have a TimeKeeper class that does all timekeeping.